# How do I Build Boost::FileSystem on Windows 7?

Tags: c++, boost, installation, codeblocks

Can someone tell me how to build boost file-system on Windows 7? I have mingw as my compiler and I use Code::Blocks 10.5 IDE.
I have downloaded boost_1_74_0.zip. What am I supposed to do from this point?
I tried reading that boost guide but things are not explained in detail of why they do that and what they do it for and its really hard to guess what they are at least for me it is.

Answer (score 0):

Boost uses a program called Boost.build (bjam) to build.  So first you need to go find a copy of that program(or you can follow the instructions to build it yourself), it is available on their website. Then you run the command bjam toolset=gcc.  That should be it. The exact section of the build manual you want is [this one.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source)

[See this page](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html) for a list of config options like static or dynamic libraries, release vs debug, etc.

Comment: okay so i have bjam now and im trying to use the bjam stuff and this is all im at command line wise  c:\boost-build>bjam -a toolset=gcc what do i put now? confused at this point

Comment: Actually there's one feature missing: that should be `bjam toolset=gcc target-os=windows`